# laravel custom login error validation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.6

I'm doing multi authentication in Laravel in user login form the error validation is working but in my company login form the error validation is not working . please help me I'm just new in Laravel and I'm just a student. Sorry for my English

this is my code in login

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required'
  ]);

  if (Auth::guard('company')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
    return redirect()->intended(route('company'));
  }
  return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'));
}
```

and this is my form where error must show

```
  <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can I ask, what is the purpose of doing it this way and why are you not just using laravels out the box auth scaffolding? I feel like you're  making alot of unrequired stress for yourself, only to achieve what laravel already gives you.

Comment: im using the auth scaffolding . but in my case i have 3 users. Company,Admin and the Users . in user form i've use what laravel already have the auth scaffolding  but in company and admin i used custom login

Comment: Well, it's up to you how you want to go about things, but I feel like you're making a simple task extremely complex. If I was in your position i'd just make a new Model called UserRole and then define a relationship between User and UserRole, you can then just add a column to your users table 'role_id' and make a small trait like UserPermission and then just define some dead simple logic so you can call stuff like if($user->isAdmin()), if($user->isUser()), if($user->isCompany())

Comment: okay nice idea. ill rid of that. but can you tell me why error is not showing?

Comment: You're not sending any errors to the view.
back()->withErrors();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'));
```

use this:

```
    $errors = new MessageBag(['password' => ['Email and/or password invalid.']]);
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
```

also add this to the top of your controller

```
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```